# enumitem itemize environment shifts text into margin, or overlaps other text

Tags: lists, enumitem, paralist

I am in the process of transitioning from using the older {paralist} package to the {enumitem} package and this question on [Suggestions for transitioning from paralist to enumitem package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/suggestions-for-transitioning-from-paralist-to-enumitem-package) suggested to use the `align=left` option. However, this is results in text overlapping. If I remove the setting, then the default `{enumitem}` package results in text being overwritten.  Not sure how to fix this...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\setlist{align=left}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[\textbf{Given:}]
    \item $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$  

    $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{1 - x}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This produces correct results with {parlist} package. Using the defaults of {enumitem}, shifts text into margin (with TeXLive2012 as of Oct 27, 2012):

[image]

and with the `align=left`, the text overlaps.

Or is there a better way for me to achieve the results that `{paralist}` produces.

Comment: It's a bug, to be fixed very soon. Anyway, when the list is properly setup (as Gonzalo shows below), this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @JavierBezos: FYI, the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301)  given here produces the same results with TeXLive2023.  Perhaps it was decided that this was not a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `leftmargin=*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[\textbf{Given:}]
    \item $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$  

    $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{1 - x}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The image only shows the relevant part:

[image]