# Incompatibility between currfile and enumitem?

Tags: incompatibility, enumitem, currfile

The MWE below yields:

> ```
>      Missing number, treated as zero.
>      <to be read again> 
>                        enit@cv@currfiledepth 
>           \item
>          testing.
> ```

for the `itemize` list. The `enumerate` list is fine.

If I remove the `\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}`, or `\setlist{leftmargin=*}`, things work fine, but I have those there for reasons as per the linked questions.

### References:

- The reason for the `\setlist{leftmargin=*}` is given in [enumitem itemize environment shifts text into margin, or overlaps other text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21669/enumitem-itemize-environment-shifts-text-into-margin-or-overlaps-other-text)
- See [Corrupted TeXLive2012 installation? (Option clash for currfile)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68684/corrupted-texlive2012-installation-option-clash-for-currfile) for [`the currfile package`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/currfile)  issue -- even though I am not using [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone), I like to have a consistent preamble.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68684/corrupted-texlive2012-installation-option-clash-for-currfile
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}

\usepackage{enumitem}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21669/enumitem-itemize-environment-shifts-text-into-margin-or-overlaps-other-text
\setlist{leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}%    This does not work!!
        \item testing.
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}% This works fine.
        \item testing.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually package bugs are not on-topic on a Q&A site. It would be better to sent bug reports for packages direct to the package author(s), or at least notify them about them as well. In this specific case I happen to be the author of `currfile`, but I still sometimes miss these kinds of "questions" here.

Comment: Works with `currfile` v0.6 but not with v0.7. However the error message seems to come from `enumitem`. I wonder if it uses `currfile` in any way...

Comment: Found it:`enumitem` loads some new font at `\begin{itemize}` which changes the `currfiledepth` counter when the file is entered and left again. However, `enumitem` already locally changed the meaning of `\value` which is used by `currfile` in an numeric test. `\value` is supposed to return a numeric value but in this case no longer does, which triggers the error message. After checking the `enumitem` manual I noticed that the author is aware about the fact that changing `\value` is "tricky". I can change the code of `currfile` to avoid this, but actually `enumitem` should leave `\value` alone.

Comment: I just uploaded `currfile` v0.7a 2012/10/28 to CTAN which avoids this error by not using `\value`. You can find the code as well at https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/currfile. I should notify the `enumitem` author too. I will close this "question" as "too localized (in time)" now. This is usually done with bug reports on this site.

Comment: It seems a bug in enumitem, indeed. I'll have a look at it.