# Equation alternative for text

Tags: environments

I'm looking for some alternative to `equation`, but for text.

I mean some enviroment which produces numbered & centered text expression.

I want to use it for linguistic data. Compare sentences (1) / (2) etc.

Do you know about something like it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate your usecase? There are several options, e.g. using `equation` in combination with `\text`, theorem-like environments etc.

Comment: I've added the goal.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50924/how-can-i-make-latex-number-my-quotes .  Or this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243662/110998 . Or this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204091/number-quote-environment-like-an-equation .  Is this what you need?