# Undesired \parindent in front of first label when using asparaenum environment

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem, paralist

When using the `asparaenum` environment from `paralist`, sometimes the `\parindent` in front of the first item is undesirable. For example, if one uses the `asparaenum` environment directly after starting the `proof` environment, then this results in an additional `\parindent` between ‘Proof.’  and the label of the first item.

How can I set up an **environment** that behaves like `paralist`, but that does not introduce this first `\parindent`? Specifically, I hope for a solution based on `paralist` or `enumitem` that does not break the optional argument for `\item`.

I attached a small example to illustrate what happens and what output I want.
Note that while I can manually modify an instance of the `asparaenum` environment to get the desired output (third part of the example), I don't know how to do this automatically with a new list environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
What \verb!asparaenum! does:
\begin{proof}
\begin{asparaenum}
\item One.
\item Two.\qedhere
\end{asparaenum}
\end{proof}

What \verb!enumitem! does:
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}[wide]
\item One.
\item Two.\qedhere
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

What I want:
\begin{proof}
\begin{asparaenum}
\newlength\saveitemindent
\saveitemindent=\itemindent
\advance\itemindent-\parindent
\item\itemindent=\saveitemindent One.
\item Two.\qedhere
\end{asparaenum}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest using `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` and then you can use inline lists via the starred variant `\begin{enunmerate*} ... \end{enunmerate*}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Does an inline list format items as paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  These might be useful references for you: [What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem), and [Suggestions for transitioning from paralist to enumitem package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/suggestions-for-transitioning-from-paralist-to-enumitem-package).

Comment: @PeterGrill The inline list from `enumitem` formats items only _within_ a paragraph. Still, using something like `\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin={\\\indent},mode=unboxed]` indeed produces output that looks right (at least as long as I don't use additional paragraph breaks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abstract what you do in the last example. The most flexible package is `enumitem`, but if you prefer `paralist` just change `\enumitem[wide]` into `\asparaenum` and `\endenumerate` into `\endasaparaenum`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{proofenum}
 {\enumerate[wide]%
  \edef\sauter@saveditemindent{\the\itemindent}%
  \advance\itemindent-\parindent
  \patchcmd{\@item}{\ignorespaces}{\sauter@restoreitemindent\ignorespaces}{}{}}
 {\endenumerate}
\newcommand\sauter@restoreitemindent{%
  \itemindent=\sauter@saveditemindent
  \def\sauter@restoreitemindent{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{proofenum}
\item One.
\item Abc
\item[XYZ] Def
\item \label{XXX} Two.\qedhere
\end{proofenum}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

(The `twocolumn` option is just to reduce the size of the following picture.)

[image]

We adjust the first `\itemindent` and then restore it as part of the final working of the first `\item` command; the `\sauter@restoreitemindent` command redefines itself to do nothing, so we won't do the reset any more and the command will do nothing bad in nested lists.