# Compilation error when including enumitem and paralist packages

Tags: lists, incompatibility, enumitem, paralist

I encounter an error when I compile a LaTeX document which includes both the `enumitem` and the `paralist` packages.
Here is my MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: & \begin{compactenum}
\item $(p_1, p_2)$ is an optimal price sequence
\item $p_2 > p_1 > 0$
\end{enum}
\\
\scshape Prove: & False
\end{tabular}


\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Case \arabic*:,leftmargin=*]
\item
It rains today.
\item
It does not rain today.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How do I fix the error?
Is there a way to define my own `compactenum` using `enumitem` so I don't need to include the `paralist` package?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don;t need to use [the `paralist` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paralist) at all. Just use the starred variant of the environments from [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) -- requires to add the `inline` option to the `enumitem` package:

[image]

If you don't want the enumerat in the tabular to be on its own line you can tweak all the paramaters used for vertical spacing.  Below I used `[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]` to achieve:

[image]

### References:

- [What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem)
- [Suggestions for transitioning from paralist to enumitem package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/suggestions-for-transitioning-from-paralist-to-enumitem-package)

---

### Compilation Error

You original compilation error can be fixed via:

1. Load `paralist` *before* `enumitem`.
2. Replace the `\end{cenum}` with `\end{compactenum}`

---

### Code: `inline`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: & \begin{enumerate*}
\item $(p_1, p_2)$ is an optimal price sequence
\item $p_2 > p_1 > 0$
\end{enumerate*}
\\
\scshape Prove: & False
\end{tabular}


\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Case \arabic*:,leftmargin=*]
\item
It rains today.
\item
It does not rain today.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### Code: `Tight Spacing`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: & \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]
\item $(p_1, p_2)$ is an optimal price sequence
\item $p_2 > p_1 > 0$
\end{enumerate}
\\
\scshape Prove: & False
\end{tabular}


\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Case \arabic*:,leftmargin=*]
\item
It rains today.
\item
It does not rain today.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### Code: `Fix Compilation Error`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: & \begin{compactenum}
\item $(p_1, p_2)$ is an optimal price sequence
\item $p_2 > p_1 > 0$
\end{compactenum}
\\
\scshape Prove: & False
\end{tabular}


\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Case \arabic*:},leftmargin=*]
\item
It rains today.
\item
It does not rain today.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not want the enumerate in the tabluar to be inline.

Answer (score 6):

Your example compiles fine if I reverse the order of loading `paralist` and `enumitem` and change `\end{enum}` to `\end{compactenum}`. I don't know if that does what you want, however. Note: when packages conflict, one of the things to try is a change in load order.

On the other hand, a `compactenum` environment can be defined with the facilities of the `enumerate` package alone, making `paralist` possibly unnecessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{compactenum}{%
  \enumerate[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt]%
}{\endenumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: &
  \begin{compactenum}
    \item $(p_1, p_2)$ is an optimal price sequence
    \item $p_2 > p_1 > 0$
  \end{compactenum}
\\
\scshape Prove: & False
\end{tabular}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Case \arabic*:,leftmargin=*]
\item  It rains today.
\item  It does not rain today.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

One might want to give a little stretchability to the four values set to `0pt` in the `\enumerate` command. That is, replace `0pt` with `0pt plus 1pt` or possible `\parskip`.
[image]

Comment: You might as well use `\newlist` to define `compactenum`, which will have  more flexibility.

Comment: @PeterGrill It wasn't clear to me from the documentation how to use `\newlist`. It seems I would also need `\setlist` to add the `0pt` settings (but I didn't have time to test all that).

Comment: Why not just use `nosep` to kill the vertical spacing rather than specifying it explicitly? (Sec. 3.8 of `enumitem`'s documentation: 'Compact Lists'.) Is less typing, though obviously no better (or worse) than your definition.

Answer (score 5):

This builds on the answers from Dan and Peter Grill. Just to show the way in which `enumitem` can be used to create a new list with the required properties. I've called this `mycompactenum` so that I can include `compactenum` from `paralist` for comparison in the same document but obviously you can just use `compactenum` if you wanted to do it this way. This solution also uses `enumitem`'s `nosep` option to kill the vertical spacing. This is equivalent to setting all of `partopsep`, `topsep`, `itemsep` and `parsep` to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mycompactenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mycompactenum,1]{nosep,label=\arabic*.}
\begin{document}
\marginpar{\texttt{paralist}}
\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: &
  \begin{compactenum}
    \item $(p_1, p_2)$ is an optimal price sequence
    \item $p_2 > p_1 > 0$
  \end{compactenum}
\\
\scshape Prove: & False
\end{tabular}\bigskip

\marginpar{\texttt{enumitem}}
\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: &
  \begin{mycompactenum}
    \item $(p_1, p_2)$ is an optimal price sequence
    \item $p_2 > p_1 > 0$
  \end{mycompactenum}
\\
\scshape Prove: & False
\end{tabular}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Case \arabic*:,leftmargin=*]
\item  It rains today.
\item  It does not rain today.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:
[image: <code>compactenum</code> from <code>paralist</code> compared with custom list from <code>enumitem</code>]