# Lists don't work with the abntex2 class and paralist package (a memoir based one)

Tags: lists, memoir, itemize

I'm writing a research project using the [abntex2](http://www.abntex.net.br/) class, which was built over memoir.

Everything was fine until I found out that lists (itemize, description, enumerate) weren't working anymore...

I've done a lot of trial and error to find out what's wrong but I can't find anything wrong. This is the minimal example that produces the errors:
([edit] the original example I posted wasn't minimal, thanks for the correction)

```
\documentclass[
12pt,% tamanho da fonte
twoside,% para impressão em frente e verso
a4paper,% tamanho do papel
]{abntex2}
\usepackage{paralist}% listas no parágrafo
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% seleção do encoding do texto de input

\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Há três bolas nesta urna, uma azul, uma vermelha, e uma verde.
   \item Uma bola está prestes a ser tirada da urna por um homem     vendado.
 \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Some of the text is in portuguese, but I don't think it's anything important to solve the issue.

That's what I get when I try to compile:

[image: error]

My OS is Linux Mint 17 and I'm using Kile 2.1.3 to typeset the document. I'm using BibTex with JabRef for the bibliography.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  It is not necessary to start your question with a greeting.  Also, your example is definitely not minimal.  Try to remove some of the packages that you load (`amsmath`, `amsfonts`) and some of the options (e.g. does the problem only occur when you load both `english` and `brazil` language support?).

Comment: That is not very minimal... !

Comment: I thought I should include every package I need, not only the ones that produce the error. I'll try to get more acquainted with the minimal example standards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a minimal example which reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,% tamanho da fonte
twoside,% para impressão em frente e verso
a4paper,% tamanho do papel
]{abntex2}
\usepackage{paralist}% listas no parágrafo

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Há três bolas nesta urna, uma azul, uma vermelha, e uma verde.
 \item Uma bola está prestes a ser tirada da urna por um homem vendado.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Removing `paralist` solves the problem. This is probably because the class already loads `enumitem` so you should use its facilities for inline lists if you need them.

For example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{inline,shortlabels}{enumitem}
\documentclass[
12pt,% tamanho da fonte
twoside,% para impressão em frente e verso
a4paper,% tamanho do papel
]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Há três bolas nesta urna, uma azul, uma vermelha, e uma verde.
 \item Uma bola está prestes a ser tirada da urna por um homem vendado.
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
\end{enumerate*}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: variant lists]

Comment: thanks a lot, you're right, paralist was the issue. according to this package documentation, though, something such as \begin{enumerate}[(i)] ... \end{enumerate} should work, but it doesn't. i'm trying to understand what this package actually does. it's a pity, for its paraenum ambient is quite useful.

Comment: `enumitem` provides the same features and more. Take a look at its documentation. I've never used `paralist` because `enumitem` provides pretty much everything I've needed, including inline lists. It can also be set up to recognise the short-label-type-specs favoured by `enumerate` which I think is what you're referring to.

Comment: @DanielDiniz Please see edit above. You can pretty much get what you want, I think, just passing a couple of options to `enumitem` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: I hadn't seen the edit on your previous comment, thanks for your help! I'm glad to see I can still have the inline tools and be able to compile the code... I'll compare enumitem to paralist to see which is easier to use and suits this document better.

Answer (score 0):

`paralist` has two options `olditem` and `oldenum`.  If you add these options, then `paralist` will not change the `itemize` and `enumerate` environment, but still provide `asparaenum` and `inparaenum`:

```
\usepackage[olditem,oldenum]{paralist}
```

Comment: I still can't understand how paralist works. The documentation says that newitem and newnum are default options; olditem and oldenum have to be explicitly declared. ok. the package's documentation states the following.

Comment: "All the itemized and enumerated environments have optional arguments to specify the format of the labels. The following examples will only work if you have loaded paralist without the options olditem and oldenum. Using the L A TEX standard classes, itemize uses the following symbols for the labels of the four list levels: • – ∗ ·. If you want to change this for a particular environment, just say something like \begin{itemize}[$\star$] and * will be used instead of the default symbol.

Comment: however, `\documentclass[
12pt,
twoside,
a4paper,
]{abntex2}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[$\star$]
 \item Há três bolas nesta urna.
 \item Uma bola está prestes a ser tirada da urna por um homem vendado.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}` doesn't work...

Comment: With the option `olditem`, `paralist` does not change `itemize`.  Therefore, you also cannot use the optional argument described in the documentation of `paralist`.  The problem is, as cfr observed, that the class `abntex2` already pulls in the package `enumitem`, which also changes `itemize`; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162799/compilation-error-when-including-enumitem-and-paralist-packages.  By the way, on this linked question, one of the answers claims that "You don;t need to use the paralist package at all."

Comment: I see... Since it's very important for me to stick with the `abntex2` class, I think I'll just tinker with `enumitem` and get rid of `paralist` altogether. I didn't know that `abntex2` already calls `enumitem` when I first got this error.

Comment: @DanielDiniz By the way, when you are satisfied with one of the answers, you should mark it as the correct answer.