# How to do `inparaenum` via `enumitem`

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, paralist

It seems that `paralist` and `enumitem` are incompatible to each other. From what I read, maybe `enumitem` is the better solution (right?).

How would I do/implement `inparaenum` with `enumitem`?

(Related is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/suggestions-for-transitioning-from-paralist-to-enumitem-package) but it doesn't really answer my specific question about `inparaenum`.)

Comment: It is the `enumerate*` environment of `enumitem`. For details, look at `§4 Inline lists`, pp.14-15 of the documentation.

Comment: I’ve been using paralist for many years. Simply works.

Comment: I also used it, long ago. Worked fine. I believe there are more possibilities for customisation with `enumitem`.

Comment: @Bernard It says "enumerate* environment undefined". Do I need to do sth specific? **Edit**: Ah, I guess I need to add the `inline` option to the package.

Comment: That's right, I forgot to mention that, sorry.